# gulp task get error: EISDIR, read?

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

```
gulp.task('dev', function () {
  watch(['public/**', '!public/index.html'], function () {
    del.sync(['web/**', '!web/.gitkeep', '!web/index.html', '!web/js/**']);
    del.sync(['cordova/www/**', '!cordova/www/.gitkeep', '!cordova/www/index.html', '!cordova/www/js/**']);
    gulp.src(['public/**', '!public/index.html', '!public/js/**'])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('web/'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('cordova/www/'));
  });
});
```

I'm using gulp setting up my development workflow. What I want to do is whenever any change happen in the `public/`, I want to wipe out everything in another two directory: `web/` and `cordova/www/`, and write everything from `public/` to `web/` and `cordova/www/`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The *dev* gulp task job keeps throwing the error: `EISDIR`, read!

Comment: Maybe related https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs/issues/39

Comment: Other suspect is that watch is firing many times and you end up deleting and creating things at the same time.

Comment: I'd check on what @Heikki commented. Do you have any symlinks inside `public/**`? A more detailed discussion of the bug is here: [https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/792](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/792)